# jQuery insert textarea value to div without affecting children elements

Tags: jquery, textarea, children

I'm trying to insert the html value of textarea `#ta` inside div `.yes` without affecting or removing the children divs with class `.no`. Currently it's removing all content of of the div   including all children elements with class `.no`.  Check jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/f2rPz/.

```
<div class="yes">test
    <div class="no">no</div>
    <div class="no">no</div>
</div>
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>

$('#ta').keyup(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.yes').html(x)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my version which will replace the `"test"` text, but keep the `.no` divs.

Basically it boils down to: You want to keep a copy of the `.no` divs outside the DOM, then reattach them after replacing the content of `.yes`.

```
$('#ta').keyup(function() {
    var no = $('.yes > .no').remove();
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.yes').html(x).append(no);
});
```

If you want to not affect *all* children, then replace the selector with `'.yes > *'` which will only select all the direct children.

http://jsfiddle.net/3PA6H/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the **append** function instead:

```
$('#ta').keyup(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.yes').append(x)
})
```

Comment: I don't want to append. I want to insert the value of textarea replacing all text inside the div but not removing it's children elements

Comment: @Pinkie: Check my answer for what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing `html()` with `append()` will do this.

Update: Here is the jsFiddle fork showing the result: http://jsfiddle.net/X7YQU/